# How to use LZW compression to compress images?

Tags: java, compression

I know how only to compress text: I use a dictionary of the 256 ASCII values and codes, but what do I use to compress images and gifs? What do I base it off of?

Comment: it is not clear if this is even a development question.

Comment: Well, ask yourself what fundamental units (elements) does a bitmap image (picture) consist of?

Comment: of 0 and 1s no??

Comment: @DanMašek Ansci code no?

Comment: The image consists of pixels (picture elements). In case of GIF, where this compression method was used, the pixels generally represented either an 8-bit grayscale intensity, or an 8-bit palette index for colour images. Hence, the symbol you'd be coding would be the intensity or palette index. | For 24bit per pixel images this kind of compression probably wouldn't be so great.